# Conditional expectation $\exp(X-Y)$ given $X+Y$

Tags: probability, normal-distribution, expectation, conditional-expectation

$X$ and $Y$ are normally distributed independent random variables with mean zero and variance 1, so $X, Y \sim N(0, 1)$.

I'm trying to calculated the conditional expectation:
$ \mathbb{E}(\exp(X-Y) \mid X+Y)$.

I've tried to write the expectation as $\exp(X+Y-2Y)$, however since $-2Y$ is not independent of $X+Y$ this clearly gives an incorrect solution. How can this expectation be calculated?

Comment: Fun fact: $X+Y$ and $X-Y$ are independent!

Comment: Ah of course, since $\operatorname{cov}(X+Y, X-Y)=0$! Thank you!